# Why doesn't Blender use Preferences->File Paths->Render->Render Output?

Tags: customization, path

I want to save render outputs (including frames for animation rendering) in a particular directory. This can be done by setting the Startup file's Scene -> Output to that path. But it seems that if I do so, the Blender project file contains that path text, and if I share the project file online, that path is exposed to the public. I want to avoid that.

So, I thought that if I set the Startup file's Scene -> Output to empty, and set the path in  Preferences->File Paths->Render->Render Output, instead. However, animation rendering failed with "permission denied, cannot save 0001.png". It seems that Blender is not using Preferences->File Paths->Render->Render Output nor Preferences->File Paths->Data->Temporary Files to save the frames.

How can I achieve what I want? That is I want to make Blender to save frames in a specific designated path, but I do not want to embed that path into the project file itself.